# Use tab key, click or double click navigation on PrimeFaces editable Datatable

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable

Essentially I would like to enable keyboard tab key and click on PrimeFaces 4.0 datatable cell.

The issue had been described as [PrimeFaces issue 6310](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6310), however the solution provided through the [showcase labs](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableCellEditing.jsf) is broken, apparently there are no showcase-labs anymore

```
<p:remoteCommand name="newRow" update="Tbl"  id="rmC"/>

<p:dataTable value="${emps}" widgetVar="wTblempl"
             var="emp" id="Tbl" filterEvent="keydown"
             editable="true" editMode="cell" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
             scrollHeight="120" scrollable="true">
    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="${Controller.addRow}"
            oncomplete="newRow()"/>

    <p:column headerText="Last Name">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="${emp.lastname}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="${emp.lastname}" tabindex="1"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Department">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText  value="${emp.firstname}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="${emp.firstname}"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Gender">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText  value="${emp.gender}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:selectOneMenu value="${emp.gender}" >
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Male" itemValue="M" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Female" itemValue="F" />

                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Status">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText  value="${emp.status}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:selectOneMenu   value="${emp.status}" editable="true">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="active" itemValue="active" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Suspended" itemValue="Suspended"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Leave" itemValue="Leave" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

**Update :**

I need to add a row which is working but when i tab in, it loses focus...

```
public void addRow(CellEditEvent event) {

    log.info("1 add");
    int r = event.getRowIndex();

    RequestContext context = RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
    List<Employee> list = (List<Employee>) context.getConversationScope().get("emp");

    if (list.size() == 1 || (r + 1) == list.size()) {

      ((List<Employee>) context.getConversationScope().get("emp")).add(new Employee());

    }
    log.info("added");
}
```

**Update 2 :**

I need to click on the first cell of row, type, (working) then tab to the next cell (working) but loses focus immediately with every other subsequent clicks or tabs unless I refresh (F5) the page

Comment: Updating the whole datatable is causing the focus lose. Please post the whole datatable code, and tell us where you are tabbing and where you want the focus after tab. Maybe we can find some workaround...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it would be easiest to solve this on the client side using JavaScript.

You can intercept pretty much every mouse and keyboard event (input) using JavaScript, see [w3schools JavaScript HTML DOM Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp).

By intercepting the onmousedown, onmouseup and onclick events you can prevent them from triggering the datatable update/refresh code.  It is likely this update code that is killing your focus.  Also, using JS you may simply re-set the focus after the update code runs - but this may lead to the issue where you cannot re-focus until page refresh.